# Why do I get a Fatal Error out of memory in Magento?

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, memory

Often when I try to add something to my cart or try to checkout I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 247463936) (tried to allocate 261900 bytes) in /home/users/domain/domain.com/webshop/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 421
```

This only just started today on two Magento webshops I'm working on.

I've done some research on the error - the memory_limit in .htaccess of Magento was already set to 256M. I've tried commenting this out and keeping it on and also been checking out the php_info(); function and this says that memory_limit is set to 256M.

This error is getting quite frustrating so help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you increase the limit?

Comment: Heh, yeah, your memory limit is set to 256M and that isn't enough. Boost it to 512M and if it runs out again, then you have some module that has a memory leak. Newer versions require an ever increased amount of memory, you're running a rather complex program afterall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing your memory limit in htaccess you should do it in in the php ini file.

Look for this line:  php_value memory_limit

If you are on a shared host, you may find that they have to help you with this. If you are on a shared host, good luck :)  I've found running a shopping cart was nightmare on every shared host I've ever tried it on.  Worth the extra bit a month for a VPS at least.

Comment: Shared hosting expects all websites running on the server to be fair and share resources. Magento does not like to play fair and expects to be given the resources it requires to run for php and mysql. It will run as fast and stably as the amount of resources you provide it for operation. If you're stingy, it blows up in interesting ways the first time any three search engines come along and index it.

Comment: Too low memory limit will throw a fatal "Allowed memory size" NOT "Out of memory"!